# creating a delay until an action happens

Tags: jquery

I want an element to slide down after the mouse has entered the element for more than 1/2 a second. I am using the delay function, but it seems that it just delays the event, rather than waits for the allotted time.

```
$('#cart_nav2').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#cart_contents').stop(true,true).delay(500).slideDown();
});
$('#cart_nav2').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#cart_contents').hide();
});
```

So I only want #cart_contents to show when the mouse has been on cart_nav2 for more than 500 ms. How is this done?

Comment: `$('#cart_contents').stop().hide();`

Comment: Where do I place that?

Comment: Where do you think you should place that?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#cart_nav2').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#cart_contents').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideDown();
});
$('#cart_nav2').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#cart_contents').stop().hide(); //this will stop your prior function from continuing
});
```